# Create Microsoft Office Wordart with Python

Tags: python

I need to create a lot of wordart for a project I am working on
old 90s wordart from Microsoft Office.

I originally tried the pythonWordArt library for python 3 but this seems to no longer be functional for Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 and 18.04
The test script runs but a white screen is returned on all 3 OSs.

Makewordart.com generates individual art however there is no way to do this automated other than through the front end with recorded keystrokes (which is not reliable)

[Css3wordart](https://github.com/arizzitano/css3wordart) contains css and js source code to generate the word art but I have no way to turn this into an image file

Is there any way for either the pythonWordArt library to be used or an alternative method?

Thanks in advance!